# How do I add a subtotal to one of the columns of my query in Google Sheets and offset it to a near by cell?

Tags: filter, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, crystal-reports-formulas

I want to offset the total of a result column of a query in Google Sheets.

I have tried googling but that doesn't help.  My query is linked to date drop-down.  The size of the query result depends upon the date selected. I want a total sum and total count of say column 2 of the query result to be shown to the left of the last row of the query result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({QUERY(A1:B, "where A >= date '"&TEXT(A1, "yyyy-MM-dd")&"' 
                              and A <= date '"&TEXT(A4, "yyyy-MM-dd")&"'"),
 {SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("♥ ♦ ♦", 
  COUNTA(FILTER(A1:A, A1:A>=A1,A1:A<=A4))-1),"♥")),"♦"); 
  "Total Sum:", SUM(QUERY(A1:B, "select B where A >= date '"&TEXT(A1, "yyyy-MM-dd")&"' 
                                            and A <= date '"&TEXT(A4, "yyyy-MM-dd")&"'"))}})
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({QUERY({VALUE(SUBSTITUTE('All payments'!D2:D, "₹",)), 'All payments'!A2:M, 
 DATEVALUE('All payments'!E2:E), 'All payments'!A2:A, 'All payments'!Y2:Y}, 
 "select ' ', Col2, SUM(Col1), Col17, Col13, Col14, Col3, Col5, Col16 
  where Col15 >= "&DATEVALUE(F1)&" 
    and Col15 <= "&DATEVALUE(F2)&" 
  group by Col2, Col17, Col13, Col14, Col3, Col5, Col16 label SUM(Col1)'', ' '''", 0);
 QUERY(QUERY(QUERY('All payments'!A2:M, R1), Q1, 0), "select sum(Col2) label sum(Col2)''"),
 "","","","","","","",""})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Its a bit  complicated to me. I will share a copy of my sheet.  Can you help?

Comment: Please go through the link 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fYfTdyU9s_U6oOr0r6_-dVQ4RmsRTQj2

I want the sum of column 'I' to be displayed to the left of the query result like I have shown - to the left and immediately after all the rows in the query. I also want to hide the " SUM " label and display just the sum result.

the link to the sheet is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Zryp2YeYYBtGCNbuXfFCbVg3TsGgVqUHyoT0Kmd5Imk/edit?usp=sharing

Please go to " Payment Sheet "